# Can you define node pointers in a base binary tree class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, binary-tree

I've created two separate binary tree classes, with some shared functions/variables and some that are not shared. So I have tried to abstract away the similarities in a base `BinaryTree` class.

```
class BinaryTree{
public:
BinaryTree(std::vector<int> &vec);

BinaryTree *left;
BinaryTree *right;
std::vector<int> dataVector;
//functions...
}
```

The derived classes share the type of data with the base class (`dataVector`). But they require the creation of new nodes of their derived type.

```
class Derived : public BinaryTree{
public:
void function(){
left = new BinaryTree();
};
```

Obviously by creating a new BinaryTree, we lose the extended functionality of the `Derived` class, but if  I  were to declare `left` and `right` as `Derived*` inside the `Derived` class, I would defeat the whole purpose of abstraction in the first place.

How would I go about implementing this if it's even possible?

EDIT: one of the derived classes might implement quick sort

```
class QuickSort : public BinaryTree{ 
public:

//chooses whether to sort itself or the children nodes recursively
void sortVector(){
if(isSorting) partition(),
else if (left->isSorting || left->areNodesSorting) left->sortVector();
else if(right->isSorting || right->areNodesSorting) right->sortVector();
}

void partition(){ /* partition implementation */};

void setupNodes(){
/* choose where to split dataVector depending on the pivot, and initialize 
the pointers - left = new QuickSort(chosenVector); etc*/ };

bool isSorting = true, isLeaf = true, areNodesInit = false, areNodesSorting = 
false;

int pivotIndex, j = 0, i = -1;
int pivotValue;

}
```

There are obviously other helper functions. And I need step by step sorting, so I've put all the variables as instance variables - should they be part of `Payload`? Also as you can see some functions use recursion and need to know of all the different children nodes as well.

Comment: I don't think inheritance applies here at all.  You have the `BinaryTree` class which represents a node, and functions that operate on nodes.  You can put those functions anywhere you want; inheritance is not required.  Ask yourself: what **IS A** relationship are you modelling here?

Comment: @RobertHarvey as I said, I already have multiple classes representing a node, `BinaryTree` is supposed to abstract away the similarities to avoid duplicate code. If there's a better way to achieve it, I'm all ears

Comment: Since in the example it's not obvious why `function` can't apply to all `BinaryTree`s, I think it would make the question better if you show an example of what "extended functionality" you're trying to achieve and why it can't be done in a single (generic?) class.

Comment: You could pass the tree class into the constructor and use composition.  If you want inheritance, what about CRTP ?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand because you missed to give an example showing the potential differences between different variants of `Derived`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, or a language that has suitable generics.

```
template <typename node>
class BinaryTree
{
public:
  BinaryTree(std::vector<int> &vec);

  node *left;
  node *right;
  std::vector<int> dataVector;
  //functions...
};


class Derived : public BinaryTree<Derived>
{
public:
  void function(){
    left = new Derived();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @yomag1234 It was mentioned in the question comments, but this is popularly known as the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4173254/3650362) (CRTP). It's worth knowing the name, so the next time it comes up you'll say "oh, that" instead of "curious *what*?"

Comment: @trentcl Thanks, I will look it up for sure.

Answer (score 3):

[Kain0_0's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/423290) contains a working solution, but at the same time it gives the wrong impression this recurring template pattern would be necessary to solve what you asked for.

What you literally asked for is much simpler to solve: just leave the `BinaryTree` as it is, and replace

```
`left = new BinaryTree();`
```

by

```
`left = new Derived();`
```

I assume the whole tree construction algorithm is part of `Derived`, and may be different in classes `Derived1`, `Derived2`, `Derived3`.

Your question is actually missing a clear description of what the differences between `Derived1`, `Derived2`, ... are. This could be the tree construction, but also the "payload" for each node of the binary tree. If that's the case, you may introduce such an attribute into the binary tree, and use the templating for this:

```
template <class Payload>
class BinaryTree
{
public:
  BinaryTree(std::vector<int> &vec);

  BinaryTree<Payload> *left;
  BinaryTree<Payload> *right;
  std::vector<int> dataVector;

  Payload *payload;
  //functions...
};
```

Alternatively, without using templates, `Payload` can be an abstract base class for different kind of base classes.

This will give you a clearer separation between the content of each node and the tree structure, allowing you to write more generalized code for the tree creation and individual code for specialized payload handling, or vice versa.

Comment: First off, thank you for an extensive answer.The differences between the different derived classes are the functions for sorting the binary tree, but there are small differences in tree construction as you've speculated.That's one of the parts I've abstracted away using functions in `BinaryTree`, with specialized templates for the differences, but it's nice knowing template-less approach works just fine. Also I'm not sure what you mean by `Payload`, if it's the data held by the node, I only need the vector, and I'm not sure how it's superior to use polymorphism only to hold instance variables?

Comment: @yomag1234:  if your different derived classes don't contain additional members, you don't need any payload. For this case, Robert Harvey's comment is correct, it makes probably no sense to use inheritance at all, just put the different tree constructions in some other class. And Kain0_0's answer then seems to be even more overdesigned than it already is.

Comment: to clarify, now I have derived classes with instance variables and functions required for different tree construction, sorting etc. I should put those in a payload class, and add it to binary tree as a pointer, and also add two other nodes of the payload class? But the derived classes (or the payload) need to know about the other nodes for construction and other functions. I'm confused as to who composites what and what the contents of different classes should be.

Comment: @yomag1234: I think it is hard to tell what would be most suitable without seeing the actual code.

Comment: I've added a concrete derived class to better explain my intent.

Comment: @yomag1234: Quicksort, as I know it, uses an array as input and produces an array  as output as well. Internally, it processes the array elements in some binary tree order, but that information is usually not kept anywhere. Is your intent to have a Quicksort algo which keeps track of that tree, and keeps track of the internal steps? For this, I would not derive Quicksort from BinaryTree, Quicksort is not a binary tree, but it works on one. By separating the algorithm from the data structure, "Quicksort" can have as many member variables as it requires without interfering with the node members.

Comment: ... of the binary tree. And no, the nodes will not require any additional payload. Your current approach is a pretty good example of how not to use inheritance, and how "composition over inheritance" resolves the issues.

Comment: All right, but I also have another class that uses binary tree, for merge sort also. But merge and quick sort have alot of duplicate code, so I could use inheritance on merge and quick sort classes so they share the duplicated code? And just leave binary tree as "unrelated" composition? Would that be the correct approach?

Comment: @yomag1234 You may want to look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c) Sorts are *functions*, they traditionally hold state in local variables

Comment: @Caleth I know, but for my purposes I require step-by-step sorting, so I need to save the state in the object until the next time the function is called.

Comment: @yomag1234: *"Would that be the correct approach?"* - well, if it is "correct" is something you have to evaluate for yourself. But from what you told us so far, I am under the impression it could be a more suitable approach than the current one. Or do you want to keep track of the member variables  `isSorting`, `isLeaf`, `areNodesInit`, `areNodesSorting`, `pivotIndex`, `j` `i`,  `pivotValue` in each of the nodes of the tree?

Comment: @DocBrown yeah I do, is that problematic somehow?

Comment: @yomag1234: technically not, but I have a hard time to imagine a use case where this would make sense.

Comment: @DocBrown I do it so I can call partiton() and other functions for each node in the binary tree. Is there a more sensible way to do this?

Comment: @yomag1234: you still did not tell us about your use case, this whole post reads like an XY problem, where you ask me if solution Y makes sense when I don't know X. Let me ask differently: why do you need to keep track of the forementioned attributes *after* the algorthm was run? What are you planning to do with these attributes *afterwards*? Why do they have to *stay* in that binary tree? What is your intent behind this?

Comment: @DocBrown As I've said previously, I need to save the attributes so I can provide step-by-step sorting, so in every step partition() is called only once, on the appropriate node. If that node is sorted, we move onto its children and so on. If the variables are local to the functions, they go out of scope and I can't continue sorting where I left off in the previous step.